# Stored procedure of search in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to write search query in this way

```
alter procedure search  
   @Book_ID int,
   @Book_name varchar(50),
   @Category_type_ID int,
   @Number_of_copies int,
   @Author_ID int
as
    select * from Book_info
    where [Book_name] like '[textboxofsearch]%'
```

There is a book info record where i search books through name and for this first i create procedure for it...record is just like this

```
  bookid book_name            Category_type_ID Number_of_copies Author_ID
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  55     Software Engineering      2               150             39
  56     mbr                       5               150             44
  57     Marketing Management      5                33             40
```

When I check it like this:

```
search mbr
```

it shows me this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure search, Line 0
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to int.

Comment: That's a sql server error message. Don't use the `mysql` tags for questions about Sql Server. MySql is a completely different database product.

Comment: What is `[textboxofsearch]`?

Comment: Is that your entire procedure?  What are all the parameters for then?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn when i post question stackover flow suggest me to add it ... :p

Comment: pleae see my update question ..

Comment: are you sending/using your parameters in the right order?

Comment: You may also have a sql injection attack vector in your code as listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just going by your incomplete procedure statement the parameters in your proc are:

```
   @Book_ID int,
   @Book_name varchar(50),
   @Category_type_ID int,
   @Number_of_copies int,
   @Author_ID int
```

And if your execution of the proc is:

```
search mbr
```

Then you have 2 issue. One is that all of your parameters are required and you are only sending in 1 parameter value `mbr`. The second is that it is seeing that first item `mbr` as invalid. Is `mbr` a variable (if so it needs to be `@mbr`) or a literal string "mbr" (if so it needs to be `'mbr'`? In either case it is going south here because mbr is not an INT and/or it is malformed from some previous statement. To help answer this better you are going to have to give more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning all the column by the book name passed I dont know why you need all there other parameters in your stored Procedure but say if you has only one parameter @Book_Name and your proc will return all the details about all the books where book name is LIKE @Book_Name, you could do something like this

```
alter procedure search  
@Book_name varchar(50)
as
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Sql =    'select * from Book_info
              where [Book_name] like '''+ @Book_name +'%'''

Execute sp_executesql @Sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way of call because the other parameters don't have default values.

In the declaration you say: `@Book_ID int`, as first param. but you pass a text for the second param.

In other words use:

```
alter procedure search  
@Book_ID int = null,
@Book_name varchar(50) = null,
@Category_type_ID int = null,
@Number_of_copies int = null,
@Author_ID int = null
as
```

after try:

```
search @Book_name = 'xxxxx'
```

or change the order of params

```
alter procedure search  
@Book_name varchar(50) = null,   
@Book_ID int = null,  
@Category_type_ID int = null,
@Number_of_copies int = null,
@Author_ID int = null
as
```

and try:

```
search 'xxxxx'
```

Comment: ok when i try this it can not show me any record